# Django could not import [function]. The path must be fully qualified

Tags: django

I recently started Django and I'm having a problem rendering a "hello world" page, the issue goes like this :

```
Could not import 'index'. The path must be fully qualified.
```

Django is not detecting my views.index function

here is the code:

**src/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^pages/', include('pages.urls')),
]
```

**pages/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', 'index', name="index"), #error
]
```

**pages/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    context = {}
    return render('index.html', context)
```

I want to render the index.html, how can I do this?

--------------- UPDATE ---------------

**CMD error**

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x00000000044D70D0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\src\src\urls.py", line 26, in <module>
    url(r'^pages/', include('pages.urls')),
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\src\pages\urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'index'
```

added `from pages import views` in urls.py

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Django 1.8+, you should import the view and include the callable in your URL patterns.

```
from .views import index

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^$', index, name="index"),
```

Note that the second argument is now `index`, the view we have imported, instead of the string `'index'`. I have also changed the regex so that it only matches the index page. Using `''` would match *every* URL.

Another option would be to import the `views` module instead of the individual view. This will make it easier to include other views e.g. `views.about` or `views.contact`.

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
```

Comment: It is giving me this error, `ImportError : cannot import name 'index'`. I am still facing the same issue with the second option. Could it be that my configurations are wrong ?

Comment: Try the relative imports as above. If that doesn't work, please update your question and show the layout of the files and directories in your project.

Comment: Updated my post for more info.

Comment: sorry, I took it off, updated again, with another error.

Comment: Found my problem, views.py should've been inside my appfolder